# How does ** work in a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned int x[4][3] = {(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(17,11,12)};
    printf("%d, %u, %u, %u \n",**x, **(x+1), **(x+2), **(x+3));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is 3, 12, 0, 0.
Shouldn't it be 1,4,7,17 as x stores the address of first element of a array?

When I tried to print

```
printf("%u, %u \n", x, &x[0][0] );
```

it shows the same address 2108666688, 2108666688

But when I try to print the array using

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<3 ; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d ",x[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I see the output as

```
3 6 9 
12 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0
```

So, what exactly is happening here? Why are the numbers not getting assigned correctly to the array?

Comment: `{(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(17,11,12)}` does not evaluate to what you expect. Take the compiler's warning serious.

Comment: Yep, always use "-Wall" with new code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = {(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(17,11,12)};
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = {3, 6, 9, 12};
```

because of [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is at work here! comma operator evaluates all its operands and yields the result of of its last operand.

So the output you see is expected. You probably meant:

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{17,11,12}};
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it returns the last number of all the operands i.e. (2,3,7,4) returns 4

Answer (score 1):

Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. That means in your case that `x` by itself is the same as `&x[0]`.

Because `x` is an array of arrays, the type of `&x[0]` is a pointer to an array, in this case `unsigned int (*)[3]`. Dereferencing this pointer is an array (of type `int [3]`), which in turn can decay to a pointer to its first element.

What the double dereferencing does is simply dereferencing the two pointers, resulting in the first element of the first array, i.e. `x[0][0]`.

That this happens to be `3` instead of `1` is because you initialize the elements using `(1, 2, 3)` which is using the *comma expression* which results in `3`.

What you probably want to do is using curly-braces for the "inner" arrays as well:

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{17,11,12}};
```

Now `**x` will result in `1` instead.

Another thing to remember is that for any array *or pointer* `x` and index `i`, the expression `x[i]` is equal to `*(x + i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Due to as I think a typo (there are used parentheses instead of braces) this declaration

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = {(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(17,11,12)};
```

is equivalent to

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = { 3, 6, 9, 12 };
```

All other elements of the array are zero-initialized.

As result the array looks like it was explicitly initialized the following way

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = { { 3, 6, 9 }, { 12, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
```

That is for example this expression

```
(1,2,3)
```

is an expression with the comma operator that yields the value of the last operand.

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
>   of the right operand. **Then the right operand is evaluated; the
>   result has its type and value**.

Consider for example

```
unsigned int x = ( 1, 2, 3 );
printf( "x = %u\n", x );
```

To get the expected result you have to substitute the parentheses with braces. For example

```
unsigned int x[4][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {17,11,12} };
```